# How to dynamically create multiple comb box based on dataset in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox, visual-studio-2017, dynamically-generated

I am trying dynamically create a combo box based on a selection that is made, and will dynamically create another combo box below it in ASP. NET.

Selection is made then another combo box gets created below and gets filled with another set of data and etc...

Comment: Please can you show what you are trying to do more clearly and if possible add an image.

Comment: Asked many times. Search for 'cascading combo box'.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion, I wanted to dynamically create a combo box and recreate combo boxes dynamically again. I could not explain exactly what I was trying to do but I found some samples that got me to the direction that I was trying to achieve based on link below.

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Creating-Dynamic-DropDownList-Controls-in-ASP.Net.aspx